# Store circle on earth

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I want to store in table places defined by coordinate `(41.67102,72.917482)` and radius `100 metes`. How can I convert 100 metes in same measure as coordinates because 1 latitude != 1 longitude. Or I should use postgis somehow?

Answer (score 0):

In postgis, the circle would be calculated with something like:

```
update PLACES set the_circle = (ST_Buffer((place_geom)::geography, 100 ))::geometry)  ;
```